# XML parsing: Error happens only in php7 script: Invalid content was found starting with element

Tags: php, xml, soap

my script generated on php7 creates a valid soap query:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v001="http://schemas.ourcompany.ru/extsys_saes2/v001/">
      <soapenv:Header>
         <v001:AuthenticationInfo>
         <userName>extsys_prod</userName><password>1234567</password>
         </v001:AuthenticationInfo>
      </soapenv:Header>
      <soapenv:Body>
         <v001:Update_SI_from_ExtSys>
           <Source>ASRZ</Source><SIID>E04867907</SIID><Status>in progress</Status><ExecutorGroupID>WG0000000000405</ExecutorGroupID><ControlGroupID>WG0000000000405</ControlGroupID><UserLogin>tb_api_user</UserLogin>
         </v001:Update_SI_from_ExtSys>
      </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

And in the SoapUP it works out correctly, but when I try to execute it from php7 SoapClient, I get an error:

```
SOAP-ENV:ServerValidation Error:cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'UserLogin'. One of '{ControlID, ChannelAddress, ChannelAddress2, ServiceImpact, Attachments, SiUpdateTime, Comment, ContactPhone, ContactName}' is expected.
```

I've already tried to add tags like:

```
<all></all>
<xs:all></xs:all>
<xsd:all></xsd:all>
```

wrapping them with different parts of the query, but all efforts are futile.

Also, when I remove

```
<UserLogin>tb_api_user</UserLogin>
```

then all is ok.
I'm probably missing something important?!..

Comment: The error seems to indicate exactly what you've done.  It's saying that it's not expecting a `<UserLogin>` element.   Removing it will get rid of that error - so what is the issue?

Comment: @nigel-ren The problem is that I need to transfer these data

Comment: OK - so does it need the UserLogin information?

Comment: yes, I do, this information is needed!

Comment: Check the documentation as to how to pass it then as it's the remote server that is trying to process this information that is rejecting it. This isn't a SOAP error as such, it's just saying the system wasn't expecting to be passed this element.